# My 2011 Kawasaki vulcan has absolutely no power to anything electrical ..,

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, kawasaki

My 2011 Kawasaki Vulcan has absolutely no power to anything electrical after placing a quick start jumper to the battery. 
There was a load pop when I had the High power Jumper on the bike. I tried to get the jumper cables off the bike as fast as I could but by that time the damage was done

I have changed out the battery, fuse relay, starter relay and I am about to change out my voltage regulator in desperation I have even bought a Staiter for it if I can't get to the bottom of this. It states on utube that the fuse box is in the fuse relay but I cannot find a way to open it to see. Could it actually be the starter?

I will trace The hot wire to the end. Today I found the computer and I am wondering if I could have fried that? That would explain no power to any of my electrical, even the horn.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally reverse the polarity of the jumper when you attached it?

Comment: No the polarity was correct. Today I find the computer. could I have fried that?

Answer (score 3):

You may have blown a fusible link.  I would trace the battery power from the battery along each cable until I found out where the voltage ends.